# how I can delete multiple rows with same id like in android sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a table as below in my sqlite database and I want to delete all the rows having a specific id - like in this case I have three columns and third column  `BELONGS` working as id like. So I wanto to delete `where belongs = abc` i.e. rows 1 and 3 and all other ones having `BELONGS = abc`.

```
sr        names         BELONGS
 1          joe          abc
 2          sid          def
 3          david        abc
```

Should I use below query ?

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "BELONGS = ?", belongsId);
```

Comment: Did you try executing it and seeing the result on the DB? What happened? Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: and what is wrong with that code?

Comment: i am able to delete only one record(row) from the table using this statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass the value `belongsId`:

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "BELONGS = '" + belongsId + "'", null);
```

Comment: with ths i am able to delete only one record with this statment

Comment: please read my question again i wanna delete all items having belongsId means i have multiple rows with same id not two different ids!

Comment: See my edit. This will delete all rows having the value of belongsId in column BELONGS

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: abc (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM names WHERE BELONGS = abc THIS ERROR IS COMING OUT TO ME

Comment: yup it worked thanks a lot  last it havent worked like this db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "BELONGS = ?", new String[]{belongsId}); but now its working after i have cleaned and rebuilt project it worked preety fine like this too :- "BELONGS = '" + belongsId + "'" but this is not right way so i did it in the former way